# Do postgres dumps from Windows and Linux differ?

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql, dump

I have a postgres database with a sequence in it. When I dump it from my development machine running Windows, it produces the following

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "some_sequence"
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

However, if I try to restore it on a Linux machine, it throws an error stating that the line `AS integer` is invalid, but works as expected when the line is removed. The linux machine is running v9.5.11 and the one on windows is postgres 10.

Does this have something to do with different operating systems, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-10.html

> Add CREATE SEQUENCE AS command to create a sequence matching an
>   integer data type

So it a new syntax in release 10 and obviously 9.5 would not understand it.

also

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

> Because **pg_dump is used to transfer data to newer versions of PostgreSQL, the
>   output of pg_dump can be expected to load into PostgreSQL server
>   versions newer than pg_dump's version**. pg_dump can also dump from
>   PostgreSQL servers older than its own version. (Currently, servers
>   back to version 8.0 are supported.) However, pg_dump cannot dump from
>   PostgreSQL servers newer than its own major version; it will refuse to
>   even try, rather than risk making an invalid dump. Also, it is not
>   guaranteed that pg_dump's output can be loaded into a server of an
>   older major version — not even if the dump was taken from a server of
>   that version. Loading a dump file into an older server may require
>   manual editing of the dump file to remove syntax not understood by the
>   older server. Use of the --quote-all-identifiers option is recommended
>   in cross-version cases, as it can prevent problems arising from
>   varying reserved-word lists in different PostgreSQL versions.

So it would work if you do the opposite - dump 9.5 and restore it to 10, but not vice versa.

Comment: Great! Actually I didn't know distributions used snapshots of postgres, which led me to believe that I was running the latest version

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it was the version conflict after all (I hadn't checked the version until I had written the question). Updating postgres on the linux machine to 10.2 resolved the issue.

Comment: Yes, restoring to a lower version is not supported.